# Load the Plugin_ParticleFX in the Ogre

Tags: iphone, ogre3d

How can i load the plugin_ParticleFx in the Ogre for the Iphone. I am workign on hte particle effect , there is problem in loading the Plugin_ParticleFX, i have add in Plugin_ParticleFX in Plugin.cfg,added the files in the Header Search paths, even though it is not showing plugin installed in the log

Answer (score 0):

On iOS the plugins are not dynamically loaded, but linked statically (and therefore integrated in the actual executable). Hence there is no need for the plugins.cfg file on that platform.

More information in the Ogre3D wiki section [Ogre3D on iOS](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=Ogre+iPhone&structure=Development).